# Initialize a composite component based on the provided attributes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm writing my custom table composite component with Mojarra JSF. I'm also trying to bind that composite to a backing component. The aim is to be able to specify the number of elements the table has in a composite attribute, later on the bound backing component will autogenerate the elements itself before view gets rendered. I've this sample code:

**Main page:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp">
<h:head />
<body>
    <h:form>
        <comp:myTable itemNumber="2" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**myTable.xhtml:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:body>
    <composite:interface componentType="components.myTable">
        <composite:attribute name="itemNumber" 
            type="java.lang.Integer" required="true" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:dataTable value="#{cc.values}" var="value">
            <h:column headerText="column">
                #{value}
                <h:commandButton value="Action" action="#{cc.action}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**MyTable.java:**

```
@FacesComponent("components.myTable")
public class MyTable extends UINamingContainer {

    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("Called");
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        // Initialize the list according to the element number
        Integer num = (Integer) getAttributes().get("itemNumber");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            values.add("item" + i);
        }
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

}
```

The issue is table gets rendered properly (in this case with two items), but `action` method **doesn't get called** when pressing the button on the lines.

If I follow the [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) for composite components, I can get it work in that way, but having to initialize the `List` each time `getValues()` is called, introducing logic into the getter method :-(.

Any idea about that? It seems to be a trouble related with overriding [`encodeBegin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeBegin%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method. I also tried initializing it on [`markInitialState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#markInitialState%28%29), but attributes are not yet available there...

---

*Tested with Mojarra 2.1.27 + Tomcat 6-7 & Mojarra 2.2.5 + Tomcat 7*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As to the cause, `UIComponent` instances are inherently request scoped. The postback effectively creates a brand new instance with properties like `values` reinitialized to default. In your implementation, it is only filled during `encodeXxx()`, which is invoked long after `decode()` wherein the action event needs to be queued and thus too late.

You'd better fill it during the initialization of the component. If you want a `@PostConstruct`-like hook for `UIComponent` instances, then the `postAddToView` event is a good candidate. This is invoked directly after the component instance is added to the component tree.

```
<cc:implementation>
    <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{cc.init}" />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

with

```
private List<String> values;

public void init() {
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    Integer num = (Integer) getAttributes().get("value");

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        values.add("item" + i);
    }
}
```

*(and remove the `encodeBegin()` method if it isn't doing anything useful anymore)*

An alternative would be lazy initialization in `getValues()` method.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC, once again. Didn't know that `UIComponent` were stateless, but definitelly it makes sense. As a solution to keep the state, I've gone with a `List` reference which is created by a `@ViewScoped` managed bean and shared with the component itself ;-)

Comment: That workaround seems to have a drawback. I usually initialize my managed bean stuff with a `preRenderView` method. I don't use `@PostConstruct` since I deal with view params that have to be set before to determine what to load. `postAddToView` seems to be called before that, so my managed bean hasn't yet that data to be shown. Is there another event I could use instead of that?

Comment: `preRenderView` should be okay as long as you skip it when  `FacesContext#isPostback()` is `true`. The bean is view scoped, right?

Comment: Using a `preRenderView` event results in two intances of the component backing being called: after one is initialized the other's getter is called, returning `null` always. So I finally have gone with a lazy initialization at the getter method. Still have to test it more deeply, will try to provide a basic case if I replay the issue in my test context.

Comment: @BalusC - It seemed simpler to make `values` part of the components state using `getStateHelper()`. As in my answer, after modifying `encodeBegin` and `getValues` to store and retrieve from cache, the component seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to store and retrieve `values` as part of the components state. Storing can happen during `encodeBegin`, and retrieving could directly happen within the getter:

```
@FacesComponent("components.myTable")
public class TestTable extends UINamingContainer {
    public void action() {
        System.out.println("Called");
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        // Initialize the list according to the element number
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer num = (Integer) getAttributes().get("itemNumber");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            values.add("item" + i);
        }
        getStateHelper().put("values",values);
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return (List<String>)getStateHelper().get("values");
    }
}
```

To avoid repeating the logic in `getValues()`, there could be additional parsing required in more complex cases, there should be a way to process and cache the attributes right after they become available, although I am not sure when and how at this point.

Either way - this seemed to be the simplest way to solve this problem.