# h:dataTable composite component, cc.attrs.var, IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jsf, datatable, composite-component

I'm trying to create my own dataTable like the primefaces one. The problem is that `cc.attrs.var` when used throws a IllegalArgumentException. So I'm wondering how I can have the var attribute like Primefaces.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:attribute name="var"/>
    <cc:attribute name="styleClass"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

    <div>Previous</div>
    <div>Next</div>

    <h:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="#{cc.attrs.var}" styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
        <ui:insert/>
    </h:dataTable>

</cc:implementation>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [`UIData#setValueExpression()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#setValueExpression-java.lang.String-javax.el.ValueExpression-) javadoc, it's not allowed to have an EL expression in `var` attribute.

> Throws:
>   IllegalArgumentException - if name is one of `id`, `parent`, `var`, or `rowIndex`

Your best bet is to create a backing component wherein you manually evaluate and set the `var` attribute of the [`UIData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) component bound to `<h:dataTable>` during the `postAddToView` event.

```
<cc:interface componentType="yourTableComposite">
    <cc:attribute name="value" />
    <cc:attribute name="var" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{cc.init}" />

    <h:dataTable binding="#{cc.table}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </h:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
```

```
@FacesComponent("yourTableComposite")
public class YourTableComposite extends UINamingContainer {

    private UIData table;

    public void init() {
        table.setVar((String) getAttributes().get("var"));
    }

    public UIData getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(UIData table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

}
```

Note that I fixed the `<ui:insert>` to be `<cc:insertChildren>`. The `<ui:insert>` can only be used in `<ui:composition>`/`<ui:decorate>`.

#### See also:

- [Initialize a composite component based on the provided attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525669/initialize-a-composite-component-based-on-the-provided-attributes)
- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)