# JSF h:datatable + f:ajax (requestscoped, Backing Component)

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, datatable, commandlink

I have to create a datatable component (as Backing Component). 
The pagination (`<h:commandLink>` outside of `<h:dataTable>`) and sorting (`<h:commandLink>` in `<f:facet name="header">`) works fine. But now i would like to add a delete function for each row. Some part of my code in my faclet(`<cc:implementation>`) looks like this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:dataTable id="table" value="#{cc.paginationPage.listings}" var="user">
        <h:column>                  
            <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>                 
            <h:commandLink id="btn">
                <span>X</span>
                <f:param value="#{cc.paginationPage.sortedColumn}" name="sorting_column"/>
                <f:param value="#{cc.paginationPage.sortedColumnDirection}" name="sorting_direction"/>
                <f:param value="#{cc.paginationPage.currentPage}" name="pagination_page"/>
                <f:param value="#{user.id}" name="user_id"/>
                <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click" render="@form" listener="#{cc.delete}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

`cc.delete` is a function in my bean (FacesComponent) and looks like this:

```
public void delete(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    System.out.println("delete!");
}
```

The problem is that `listener` in `<f:ajax>` is ignored. The ajax calls only the init function in the bean (set with `<f:event listener="#{cc.init}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>`). There's no error or exception. Even if i try to call something like `listener="#{cc.doesentExist}"`.

I believe my problem is in point 4. of [BalusC's list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value) (same like  kavain's problem in the comments). 
But i dont know how to fix it, cos i dont can change my bean to ViewScoped. So, how can I get the `<h:commandLink>` working in this scenario? Could anyone please help me?

PS: 
Unfortunately i can only use plain JSF (2.3) (no frameworks like primefaces etc. allowed).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run your app in debelopment mode?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes its set to development.

Comment: If i add a binding to the `<h:datatable>` and set the value of the `<h:datatable>` in the `init()` function in facescomponent, quite similar like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555893/hdatatable-composite-component-cc-attrs-var-illegalargumentexception) it works, but im not sure if this is the way to go. Could someone please clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i add a binding to the <h:datatable> and set the value of the <h:datatable> in the init() function in facescomponent, quite similar like in this example it works, but im not sure if this is the way to go, but it worked.