# pass parameter to backing bean with include

Tags: jsf, include, param

I'm using a include page and want to pass an ID of an object from the main page to the backingbean of the include page.

I tried like this

```
<ui:include src="/fleetreport/vehicledocument_list.xhtml">                      
    <ui:param name="fleetvehicleid" value="#{contractDetail.contract.fleetVehicleId}"/>
</ui:include>
```

And in the backingbean of vehicledocument_list.xhtml

```
Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
if (params.get("fleetvehicleid") != null) {
    fleetVehicleId = new Integer(params.get("fleetvehicleid"));
}
```

But params.get("fleetvehicleid") is always null.

Is there a way to pass this id parameter to the bean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve value of a ui:param in the backing bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459854/how-to-retrieve-value-of-a-uiparam-in-the-backing-bean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
Object p1 = faceletContext.getAttribute("fleetvehicleid");
```

Look similar question
[How to retrieve value of a ui:param in the backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459854/how-to-retrieve-value-of-a-uiparam-in-the-backing-bean)